# Rails respond_with correctly shows form with validation but with index path URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With at least two ressources, the `create` action in the controller has a `respond_with` method.

If I cause a validation error, the form is correctly shown with validation error, but the URL in the browser shows the index path of the ressource.

For example:

```
  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params).decorate
    success = @service.save
        
    if success
      redirect_to client_path(@service.btn.client, :anchor => "servicesList"), notice: "Service with service_id: '#{@service.try(:object).try(:service_id)}' was successfully created"
    else
      validation_errors_string=""
      validation_errors_string = "#{@service.errors.map { |e,s| s }.join('<br>')}"
      flash[:alert] = "#{validation_errors_string}".html_safe
      @btn = @service.btn
      respond_with(@service)
    end
  end
```

.... brings me to `/services`, rather then the original url of the form of `/clients/55555/services/new` .   I would not expect that URL, but the form is correctly shown with validation errors.

Chanigng the `respond_with` to

```
respond_with(@service, location: new_service_path(@service, client_id: @service.client.id))
```

.... still brings me to  `/services`.  The form is correctly shown with validation errors; I just would not expect the `/services` URL / path.

Doing:

```
respond_with(@service, location: request.referer)
```

.... also brings me to  `/services` .   The form is correctly shown with validation errors; I just would not expect the `/services` URL / path.

A different ressource & action, `ClientsController#create` is having similar behavior with `respond_with`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this standard behavior of `respond_with`?   Nothing seems broken functionaly, but I doubt this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Might have nothing to do with it but are sure it's fine to pass the decorator to respond_with? Can you try passing the ActiveRecord instance itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behaviour in Rails. `respond_with`, which isn't a core part of Rails but provided by a gem called [responders](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders), follows the same patterns as Rails' core behaviour.

When using Rails' RESTful resource pattern (e.g., if you specify `resources :services` in your `config/routes.rb`), the form data is sent in an HTTP POST request to the `/services` endpoint. The Rails router then converts the form data to the `params` object and passes that data to the `ServicesController#create` method to handle.

If that data turns out to be invalid, the server can't redirect to show the new form again, because to do so would lose the form data that you just submitted - and generally we want to redisplay that. So the usual course of action is to re-render the same page template as the user saw in `/services/new`, but with the partially complete, invalid copy of `@service` instead of a completely empty one.

Because no redirect occurs, the browser URL bar shows `/services`, because that's the endpoint that's returned the HTML the user is looking at. But the form is still representing a new, as-yet-unsaved record, and submitting it (hopefully with amendments that make the record valid) will go to `POST /services` just as they did the first time.