# Rails routes issue on create button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have given model level validation in users model for email,first name and last name as given below

```
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
```

now if i click create button without filled above info from view, it must redirect or render to same page, but in my case didn't worked.
controller and view code as below.

```
# new method
def new    
  @user = MUser.new
end

# create method
def create
  @user = MUser.new(m_user_params)
    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      redirect_to users_path, notice: "user saved successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'please filled required information'          
      render 'new'
    end
end

# view code
<%= form_for(@user,:url => { :controller => "users",:action => (@user.new_record?) ? 'create' : 'update' }) do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit 'create user' , :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-md form_submit active' %>&emsp;
   <%= f.label :first_name, "first name", class: 'asterisk' %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control ", placeholder: first name）" %>
   <%= f.label :last_name, "first name", class: 'asterisk' %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control ", placeholder: last name）" %>
<% end %>
```

now if any one field given empty and click create button then need render on same page.

routes as below

```
get 'users' => 'users#index'
get 'users/new' => "users#new"
post 'users' => "users#create"
get 'users/:id/edit' => 'users#edit'
patch 'users/:id/update' => 'users#update'
get 'users/:id/destroy' => 'users#destroy'
delete 'users/:id/destroy' => 'users#destroy'
resource :users
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting in your logs?

Comment: @Jon, didn't get any error if i create button without filled required fields it's redirected to `/user` page, and displayed validation messaged, but instead of this need to redirect or render on `/users/new` that's same page and need to shows validations messages.

Comment: @dbugger sorry to forget, it'e type mistake while putting questions on stackoverflow, please check, i have re-corrected type mistake

Comment: does the redirected page (`/user`) still show the `form` ?

Comment: @LamPhan if i render `render 'new'` it's goes to `/users` page which is list screen, instead of this need to go on same page, cause `render 'new'` technically show `/users/new` page

Comment: i asked did you `see` the list users is rendered or the form still there ?

Comment: no, it's opened same page `'/users`  after `render 'new'` means `/users` screen displayed create page after click on create button

Comment: in case the form is still there, then it's rails default behavior, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67694840/rails-respond-with-correctly-shows-form-with-validation-but-with-index-path-url/67699083#67699083) explains very well the reason.

Comment: how can show `/users/new` on render?